# Highlight Wordpress parent menu item when submenu link active

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a simple menu in Wordpress.

I need to highlight the ACTIVE PARENT MENU ITEM when a submenu item is selected.

The problem is, whenever I do that via current-page-parent/current-page-ancestor - ALL menu items in the dropdown are have the active style applied to them as well as the parent.

Any ideas how I can do this without touching the submenu item styles?

```
<ul id="menu-main" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li id="menu-item-249" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-249 dropdown"><a href="#">Parent Menu Item</a>
    <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-251" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-251"><a href="#">Sub-menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress automatically add some classes to the ancestor of the current item, that you can use to highlight the parent item. You can see in your code, how WordPress added the classes `current-page-ancestor` and `current-menu-ancestor`.

I recommend you to use .current-menu-ancestor because it will work with all the object types.

Comment: Perfect. thanks.

.current-page-ancestor, .current-menu-ancestor {
background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

Comment: I want to highlight main menu item when I click on sub-menu item.. please suggest

Comment: These properties helped me out: .current_page_parent > a { }  
 .current-menu-parent > a { }

Comment: .current-menu-parent > a {
color: #fa4616 !important;
} This worked for me.